# Is there meaning in the minimal instances of a variable you need to write a rational expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, rational-functions

This is something I've never thought about before. Given a rational function $f \in \mathbf{k}(x)$, the minimum number of $x$ you need to write down a formula for $f$ on its domain is well-defined. My cute example is that the rational function
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1} \;\;=\;\;1-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
only needs one $x$ to be expressed, which means here that $f$ is invertible on its domain: there exists an $f^{-1}$ with range equal to the entire domain of $f$. But is this interesting? Like, can we say something general relating the minimal number of $x$s needed to express $f$ and the number of sections of $f$?

Comment: Do you count $x^k$ as one instance, or $k$? And do you require the domains of rational functions to be identical for the functions to be identical? Or just that the domains differ by finitely many points? For example, do you consider $\frac{x}{x(x-1)}$ and $\frac{1}{x-1}$ to be the same?

Comment: Either way, for starters, given $f=\frac{p}{q}$ you can split $q$ into irreducibles, and then by long division get denominators of degrees strictly less than the irreducibles.

Comment: @Servaes To your questions, I don't know. I haven't thought about this deeply. Whichever answer leads to something interesting? My inclination would be to say two functions are the same if they agree on a dense subset of $\mathbf{k}$ (so let $\mathbf{k}$ be a topological field now). The language of sheaves could creep in here.

Comment: @Servaes Yeah, you can always factor and do long-division and partial fraction decomposition to rewrite a rational function. But, subquestion: will doing these things result in an expression for the function having the fewest "number of $x$"?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is sometimes convenient for either of two purposes:

- (As you noted) finding the inverse function quickly;

  - In particular, it sometimes makes it obvious whether the function increases or decreases as $x$ increases;
- It makes differentiation with respect to $x$ a bit simpler.

And maybe in some contexts the fact that $\dfrac 1 {x+1}$ is immediately recognizable as the sum of a geometric series is useful.